# Am I less likely to get into a masters in finance or economics with a bachelors in business administration than I would with a bachelors in finance?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, business-school

I had always thought I have going for a bachelors in finance, but it turns out I am getting a bachelors in business administration with concentrations in finance & applied analytics. I plan on going to grad school for a masters in finance or economics and even a possible doctorate if I go the research/econ route. Will this hurt my chances of getting into grad school with a more common and not as prestigious degree? Are my employment aspects lessened?

Answer (score 1):

BBAs are probably the most common business undergraduate degrees in the US. Nobody will care that it doesn't say Bach. Finance. You should do your best to highlight that your concentration was in finance when you apply for your graduate work.